# Identity flow not working in IE 10

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

The identity call back doesn't seem to be working at all in IE 10.  After the oath windows open, accepting and the redirect back to the mobile service endpoint happens the window doesn't close.   You can see this here:

http://tilsa.azurewebsites.net

Click on the top on any of the logins (or vote) and you'll notice this happening.  It works fine in Firefox and Chrome and there are no issues in the javascript console.

Can you offer any help with this?

Comment: Can you try updating to the latest SDK to see if the issue still exists? Replace the line in your .html file where you have `<script src='https://tilsa.azure-mobile.net/client/MobileServices.Web-1.0.0.js'></script>` to use `<script src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mobileservices/MobileServices.Web-1.1.0.min.js'></script>` instead.

Comment: Thanks @carlosfigueira, I think you were the one that answered my forum post as well.  If you post an answer here I'll accept it otherwise I'll post one later to help out others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with the login in Internet Explorer in the original version of the HTML/JS mobile services SDK. Try updating it to the latest version, and the problem should be gone. To do that, replace the line

```
<script src='https://YOUR-SERVICE.azure-mobile.net/client/MobileServices.Web-1.0.0.js'></script‌​>
```

with

```
<script src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mobileservices/MobileServices.Web-1.1.0.min.‌​js'></script>
```